# Bulletproof AirPlay Connectivity for Meeting Rooms?

Tags: networking

I give presentations to large audiences showing an iOS app's functionality. The mobile device I use has a protective sleeve that cannot be removed. My current setup is to run AirServer on my MacBook, connect my iOS device to the MacBook using AirPlay mirroring, and connect my MacBook screen to projector via VGA or HDMI.

Assuming I can't use a wired connection from the device, what is the best way to ensure I can project the iOS screen every time, without it failing? It seems like the connection sometimes drops or won't connect, and it's been very difficult to have confidence that the presentation will go well. There is a theory that this is because the iOS device and the laptop jump access points. Another theory is that there is too much wifi traffic given the number of people in the room with mobile devices and laptops. I have an opportunity to recommend a brand new setup, including a dedicated Apple TV, separate networks, etc.. I am not an expert in this area, and would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Ever considered a pico projector for your iPhone? That would let you cut out the middleman completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, there's absolutely nothing you can do as you don't control the RF environment in the areas you're presenting.

You'll need to consider changing up your case so you can use a hard-wired video connection. If you've noticed, this is what Apple does in their keynotes. Even they don't trust Airplay enough to use it for critical presentations.